# Timm provides petrained models. On which dataset these weights are trained on?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface

How to find out on what dataset the petrained models provided from Timm are trained on?

```
pretrained_resnet_34 = timm.create_model('resnet34', pretrained=True)
```

https://timm.fast.ai

https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models#models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trained on `ImageNet1k` datasets. However, there are some models trained on the bigger dataset, `Imagenet22k`. Most of time, this is indicated in the name of the model.

Comment: well, from my example, I cannot read that from the model name.

Comment: In your case is imagenet1k. The default is imagenet1k, so when there is no extra info in name, it's imagenet1k.

Comment: For resnet18 the same?

Comment: yes, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

ImageNet(https://image-net.org/download) mostly, and can be determined by model name, it's mentioned in the license here https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models#licenses

The author notes that all are pretrained on ImageNet that there are "Several weights included or references here were pretrained with proprietary datasets " -  https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models#licenses (5/4/2023). Basically Google and FB have models here (with datasets that are not shared with the author) You can check which model you are using more thoroughly by reading the associated arxive.org doc using this model:document list here https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. 


However,  I also found out: PyTorch 2.0 gives extra support for timm and huggingface:
https://pytorch.org/get-started/pytorch-2.0/#accelerating-hugging-face-and-timm-models-with-pytorch-20